# Bash Script - Disable Wireless Connections

Tags: wifi, bashrc, netctl

```
OS: Arch Linux
Network Manager: Netctl
```

I am trying to write a bash script that will disable all current network connections and turn off wifi on my system. I currently have the following, but after running netstat it doesn't appear to disconnect my current TCP Connections.

```
alias wifioff='sudo netctl stop wlp3s0-network'       # Stop WiFi
```

How should I go about terminating all active connections in this script? I assume I would only need to do this with TCP connections, as UDP would be connectionless... Right?

Answer (score 1):

Turning network interfaces down does not in general cause TCP connections to terminate. That's the way TCP/IP is designed. The idea is that links that go down should not cause the upper layers to give up on connections because the problem might be transient and go away quickly, or routing protocols may promptly install alternate routes and heal the network that way. Think of unplugging your ethernet cable for a few seconds and plugging it back in: TCP sessions that are actively transmitting data through it will lose a few packets, incur a few short timeouts, and recover quickly (maybe after engaging slow start) once the cable is restored. To change this would have TCP much too fragile as every single little network hiccup becomes fatal to impacted TCP sessions.

That being said, you still want to manually terminate active TCP connections from a shell script. I'm afraid there is no obvious interface in Linux to find TCP connections and force them to terminate.

One way I can think of is originating fake `RST` packets (e.g. through a tun/tap interface) to fool the kernel into thinking that the other end has terminated the connection. This is a lot of effort because you have to set up the tun/tap interface (or other method of injecting packets into the kernel), find the correct remote IP address, port number, and TCP sequence number for the spoof, and manually build IP and TCP headers!

A little bit of googling reveals [this method using `tcpkill`](https://superuser.com/questions/561305/is-there-a-way-to-kill-an-open-connection-without-killing-the-process/564058#564058). Perhaps that will work for you.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried TCPkill, doesn't seem to have the desired effect. when running an "netstat -tulanp" prior to turning off the interface I see that there are still established connection and if I try to run it after turning off the interface it errors out saying that there is no such device... lol